# How host locally Material Design Iconic Font into a vue app

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, webpack-style-loader, material-design-icons

I have developed a Vue 2.6 SPA using Vuetify and Material Design Icons that is included as described [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/), but some elements of the SPA (partially derived by a public template) use also "**Material Design Iconic Font**". I would like to host locally the "**zmdi**" icons, instead of using CDN, and following the instructions reported [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-design-iconic-font) I installed this additional icon pack using:

```
npm install material-design-iconic-font
```

I don't know how to correctly include "**zmdi**" icons into the VUE app.
Could anyone suggest the easiest way to host Material Design Iconic Font within the VUE SPA?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved using

```
import "material-design-iconic-font/dist/css/material-design-iconic-font.css";
```

into "main.js".

I have to include something else into "vue.config.js" to instruct webpack to correctly handle this css file?